# Language, Proof and Logic Exercise 14.13 (Fitch)

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

[image]

Having trouble proving this. I know how to prove the first conjunct of the conclusion, but not the second one. Picture shown is the attempt proof of the second conjunct (rules haven't been added yet). I have a feeling that we need to use ∀Intro for the second conjunct of conclusion as well as ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x v z = y)) part of premise.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Answer (score -1):

> I have a feeling that we need to use ∀Intro for the second conjunct of conclusion as well as ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x v z = y)) part of premise.

Yes, you need to apply Universal Elimination thrice, once to each arbitrary term.

You can then derive three disjunctions through Conditional Eliminations.

Up next is a *nested* disjunction elimination, where you use equality eliminations and disjunction introduction; you are aiming to obtain `a=b v a=c v b=c` at the end of each sub-proof.

Recall, `a=d` and `b=d` entails `a=b` by Equality Elimination.

And so on.

[See also this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68650/lpl-fitch-proof-exercise-14-13-help)